# Google Gauge Float Value With Trailing Zeroes

Tags: google-visualization

I'm using a [Google Gauge Chart](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/gauge).  All is working fine, except I noticed when I feed it a float value, if the value is a whole number (e.g. 17.0), the gauge shows 17 as the value instead of 17.0.  If I give the gauge 17.3 as the value, it correctly shows 17.3.  Is there any way to format the actual value output on the gauge?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use the [`NumberFormat` class](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/reference#numberformat)

```
var formatter = new google.visualization.NumberFormat( {pattern: '0.0'} );
formatter.format(data, 1);
```

see following example...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  callback: function () {
    var query = new google.visualization.Query('https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Z-eKZJ_XbmnoLYyG4cht40KMo07_CYnLP-hPi1ZBjnw/edit#gid=0');
    query.send(handleQueryResponse);

    function handleQueryResponse(response) {
      var data = response.getDataTable();

      var formatter = new google.visualization.NumberFormat( {pattern: '0.0'} );
      formatter.format(data, 1);

      var options = {
        redFrom: 0,
        redTo: 35,
        yellowFrom: 35,
        yellowTo: 65,
        greenFrom: 65,
        greenTo: 100,
        minorTicks: 5
      };

      new google.visualization.Gauge(document.getElementById('gaugechart')).draw(data, options);
    }
  },
  packages: ['gauge']
});
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="gaugechart"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks!  I didn't realize there was a bunch of different formats available.